# Proper Page Editor for General Link in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

Can you help me get the General Link field working in the Sitecore Page Editor.

I can see a small helper "Insert link" and after clicking on it, the "Insert an internal link" form will popup. This happens by default when I'm in edit mode in the page editor

This works fine however I also need to be able to "Insert an external link" from the Page editor. I know that this can be achieved in admin part of Sitecore, but how this behavior can be achieved in Page Editor?

Is it possible to setup Sitecore, so a user can edit an External link to an external site (for example: Microsoft profile link on user profile page)?

Thank you.

Comment: If the field really a `General Link field` or is it possibly an `Internal Link field`?

Comment: This is a General Link field. I haven't used Internal Link field.

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted Sitecore support and this is a known bug. You need to contact their support and they will provide you with a patched dll to resolve this issue.

Ask for Sitecore.Support.324486.dll

Answer (score 0):

The *"General Link"* field experience has been improved since Sitecore CMS 6.6.0 rev. 121203 (aka Update-2). Sitecore has redesigned the way of editing *"General Link"* field using Page Editor. Now you can select and edit any kind of links that *"General Link"* field supports.

Please take a look at the reference numbers 311859, 352558 and 324486in Sitecore CMS release notes on SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

Best Wishes, Oleg