# Sitecore sc:link field type default set

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

How can I set the default type of link a control should show in page editor? I have  field inside a repeater, and using pageeditor they can enter a new item, and this is one of the fields. How can I set it so that when they do that, and click on editing the link, they enter an external link? In the content editor, they can choose 'external link' as the option, but in page editor, they can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to contact support on this one. It appears that the Page Editor defaults to the "Internal Link" dialog for General Link fields.

This was [asked here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294424/proper-page-editor-for-general-link-in-sitecore) several months ago and someone commented that Sitecore support supplied them with a patch.

In the meantime, if you need a workaround, you can enter the text below into the general link field as a RAW value. It will trick the Page Editor into thinking it's an external link.

```
<link linktype="external" url="" anchor="" target="" />
```

Comment: where exactly do I add this? on the .aspx page?